# Forward events to link

Tags: jquery

I have a clickable div which contains a lot of other elements, but when it is clicked it opens a page.

One of my users asked if it would be possible to make this area clickable for right click and show the context menu which normally appears for normal links (`<a></a>`) such as Open link new tab/Open link new window etc... Also middle mouse click open is automatically on new page which also would be nice.

I'm not able to change this element to `<a>` tag as it would break other functionality. So I had an idea to forward mouse events from the div to a hidden link element, but I haven't got to far...

Could you suggest a method which would allow me to implement such functionality?

Here is my example with the click forwarding, but it does not work.

```js
var a = $('a');

$('#aaa').on('click', function(e) {
  a.click(e);
});
```

```css
#aaa {
  background: #f00;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" style="display:none;">Test</a>

<div id="aaa">
  blabla
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to register click event for $('a') then you can trigger that event from other elements.

```js
var a = $('a');
a.on('click',function(e){
  alert('i am clicked from out');
});
$('#aaa').on('click', function(e) {
  a.trigger('click');
});
```

```css
#aaa {
  background: #f00;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" style="display:none;">Test</a>

<div id="aaa">
  blabla
</div>
```